# Lost BRP card! Can I re-enter the UK without it?

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I have lost my Biometrics residence permit card for the UK whilst traveling overseas however my plans have now changed and I am going home instead of starting work in the UK, I am a New Zealand citizen so don’t need a visa to visit the UK, (I just need one to work). Can I get in as a visitor as I have no intention of working and have flights home or will I need to apply for a new BRP card to get back into the UK?

Comment: [See this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/130171/refused-entry-at-gare-du-nord-due-to-stolen-brp). If I were you, I would replace the BRP before returning.

Comment: @MJeffryes It's unfortunate that the question you linked to doesn't mention the nationality of the OP. It looks like the OP there was a visa-national, while the OP here can enter the UK visa-free. My guess is that he should be OK if he can produce a police report for the stolen item and onward tickets to New Zealand in a reasonable time frame. (Don't ask me what 'reasonable' is!)

Comment: Have you reported it lost https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits/lost-stolen-damaged?

Comment: @Redd Herring Maybe, maybe not. Non visa nationals can still be denied entry. Which is why I would get the card replaced before returning, if at all possible.

Comment: What is the purpose of your visit to the UK?

Comment: If you're no longer going to be a UK resident, you wont need your BRP

Answer (score 3):

If you have ILR, it is vital that you *do not* enter the UK as a tourist, since that can lead to loss of your ILR. From [VisaLogic](https://www.visalogic.net/uk/indefinite-leave-to-remain/4/50):

> There are a number of circumstances that may cause you to lose your Indefinite Leave To Remain status. For example, if you leave the UK and upon return are granted leave to enter the UK other than for an indefinite period.

If you turn up at the border you *might* be let through as a resident without your BRP, but if the border agent mistakenly clears you as a tourist then you will accountable for the mistake (not them!) If you don't have ILR, it seems it won't lead to your visa being cancelled but it's likely to cause problems later down the line, e.g. when you apply for IRL. Also, don't overstay as a tourist because that will affect your chances at future visa applications.

Comment: What if OP enters the UK through Ireland?